# microphone does not work after suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I noticed that after I suspend Ubuntu 16.04 internal mic stops working. I spent two days to find the reason without any result.

What I found:
1) if I start windows and than again Linux it is working
2) If I click on sound icon (left top corner) I will see only regulation of output (then all is fine and works); after suspend I will see also regulation of microphone
3) in Pulseaudio Internal microphone seems to be unplugged after suspend
4) restart does not help (only booting windows helps)

what can cause the microphone "unplugging" and how can I fix it ?

upd:
If I turn off my sound system (it has only output, no input) it works fine and internal mic is plugged in. When I physically plug soundsystem it makes internal mic unplugging.